# Pass simple numpy array to C via SWIG

Tags: python, c, numpy, swig

I want to pass numpy array of known size and type via SWIG to C function

```
# .py
data = numpy.arange( N , dtype=numpy.int32 )
external_c_function( data )

# .i
extern void external_c_function( int32_t* data );

# .c
void external_c_function( int32_t* data)
{
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I will get an error:

```
TypeError: in method 'external_c_function', argument 1 of type 'int32_t *'
```

What is the easiest way to pass numpy array to SWIG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy.i`. Just have a look at http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/SWIG_NumPy_examples